# Implementing `Deref` for slices/`?Sized`

Tags: rust

I'm working on a library implementing allocators (https://github.com/JonathanWoollett-Light/array-allocators) which can be used in shared memory.

I have a type which currently implements `Deref` and `DerefMut` on `T: Sized` and need it to implement on `T: ?Sized` to support slices.

This type is `TypedLinkedListArrayWrapper`:

```rust
pub struct TypedLinkedListArrayWrapper<'a, const N: usize, T: ?Sized> {
    pub wrapper: LinkedListArrayWrapper<'a, N>,
    __marker: PhantomData<T>,
}
```

which implements `Deref` and `DerefMut`:

```rust
impl<'a, const N: usize, T> Deref for TypedLinkedListArrayWrapper<'a, N, T> {
    type Target = T;

    fn deref(&self) -> &Self::Target {
        unsafe { &*(self.wrapper.deref() as *const [LinkedListArrayBlock]).cast() }
    }
}
impl<'a, const N: usize, T> DerefMut for TypedLinkedListArrayWrapper<'a, N, T> {
    fn deref_mut(&mut self) -> &mut Self::Target {
        unsafe { &mut *(self.wrapper.deref_mut() as *mut [LinkedListArrayBlock]).cast() }
    }
}
```

If I change `T` to be `T:?Sized` here I get the errors

```
error[E0277]: the size for values of type `T` cannot be known at compilation time
   --> src/linked_list.rs:166:54
    |
162 | impl<'a, const N: usize, T: ?Sized> Deref for TypedLinkedListArrayWrapper<'a, N, T> {
    |                          - this type parameter needs to be `std::marker::Sized`
...
166 |         unsafe { &*std::ptr::addr_of!(*self.wrapper).cast() }
    |                                                      ^^^^ doesn't have a size known at compile-time
    |
note: required by a bound in `ptr::const_ptr::<impl *const T>::cast`
   --> /home/jonathan/.rustup/toolchains/nightly-x86_64-unknown-linux-gnu/lib/rustlib/src/rust/library/core/src/ptr/const_ptr.rs:60:23
    |
60  |     pub const fn cast<U>(self) -> *const U {
    |                       ^ required by this bound in `ptr::const_ptr::<impl *const T>::cast`
help: consider removing the `?Sized` bound to make the type parameter `Sized`
    |
162 - impl<'a, const N: usize, T: ?Sized> Deref for TypedLinkedListArrayWrapper<'a, N, T> {
162 + impl<'a, const N: usize, T> Deref for TypedLinkedListArrayWrapper<'a, N, T> {
    |

For more information about this error, try `rustc --explain E0277`.
error: could not compile `array-allocators` due to previous error
```

---

This is on top of `LinkedListArrayWrapper`:

```rust
pub struct LinkedListArrayWrapper<'a, const N: usize> {
    allocator: &'a LinkedListArrayAllocator<N>,
    index: usize,
    size: usize,
}
```

which implements `Deref` and `DerefMut`:

```rust
impl<'a, const N: usize> Deref for LinkedListArrayWrapper<'a, N> {
    type Target = [LinkedListArrayBlock];

    fn deref(&self) -> &Self::Target {
        let allocator = unsafe { &*self.allocator.0.get() };
        &allocator.data[self.index..self.index + self.size]
    }
}
impl<'a, const N: usize> DerefMut for LinkedListArrayWrapper<'a, N> {
    fn deref_mut(&mut self) -> &mut Self::Target {
        let allocator = unsafe { &mut *self.allocator.0.get() };
        &mut allocator.data[self.index..self.index + self.size]
    }
}
```

where `LinkedListArrayBlock` is:

```rust
pub struct LinkedListArrayBlock {
    size: usize,
    next: Option<usize>,
}
```

How can I do this?

Comment: Seems like you have a `Deref` implementation for your `TypedLinkedListArrayWrapper` type already. What is your question? Are there any compilation errors, does something work not as expected, are there any conflicting requirements?

Comment: @yeputons Added clarification on issue.

Comment: Avoid using cast

Comment: Please post the full error from `cargo check`, not your IDE.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So I found a solution.

An important topic here relates to https://doc.rust-lang.org/std/ptr/trait.Pointee.html. Unfortunately this is nightly and requires `#![feature(ptr_metadata)]`.

A solution is to use a custom type for slices to embed the meta data needed for a slice:

```rust
pub struct SliceLinkedListArrayWrapper<'a, const N: usize, T> {
    pub wrapper: LinkedListArrayWrapper<'a, N>,
    pub len: usize,
    __marker: PhantomData<T>,
}
impl<'a, const N: usize, T> Deref for SliceLinkedListArrayWrapper<'a, N, T> {
    type Target = [T];

    fn deref(&self) -> &Self::Target {
        unsafe { &*std::ptr::from_raw_parts(std::ptr::addr_of!(*self.wrapper).cast(), self.len) }
    }
}
impl<'a, const N: usize, T> DerefMut for SliceLinkedListArrayWrapper<'a, N, T> {
    fn deref_mut(&mut self) -> &mut Self::Target {
        unsafe {
            &mut *std::ptr::from_raw_parts_mut(
                std::ptr::addr_of_mut!(*self.wrapper).cast(),
                self.len,
            )
        }
    }
}
```

A more generalized solution is likely possible although may be awkward.